# How to use excel text function "NUMBERVALUE" from Apache POI formula

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to evaluate a formula cell that has a text function "NUMBERVALUE", then I got an exception
***Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: _xlfn.NUMBERVALUE***

Interesting enough, when I try to regist this function  `WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction("NUMBERVALUE",  new NumberRValue());`
it gives me another error:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NUMBERVALUE is not a function from the Excel Analysis Toolpack.**

I also tried to use the user-defined functions by implementing FreeRefFunction, it backs to the first error again.

Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: _xlfn.NUMBERVALUE

**How to implement a text function in Apache POI?**

Comment: Maybe you could try creating a UDFFinder and aggregating it with the built-in finder(s) - see AggregatingUDFFinder. Have a look at `public static XSSFFormulaEvaluator create` to see how to create a formula evaulator that uses a custom UDFFinder

Comment: see also - https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction` only works for functions `apache poi` at least knows per name. This are all functions listed through:

```
java.util.Collection<String> unsupportedFuncs = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getNotSupportedFunctionNames();
System.out.println(unsupportedFuncs);
```

All the listed functions can be registered using `WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction` either as `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Function`, when in `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.atp.AnalysisToolPak` or else as `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction` if not.

But `NUMBERVALUE` function is not in this list. So this only can be added as a user defined function. See [User Defined Functions](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) of `apache poi`'s documentation.

The function must implement `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction` and must be registered in UDF toolpack of the `Workbook`.

Following complete example shows a basic implementation of `_xlfn.NUMBERVALUE`. Implementation is done using the description in [NUMBERVALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/numbervalue-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879). It is a working draft until now and might need to be improved to better fulfill compatibility to Excel's own results.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.AggregatingUDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.DefaultUDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.UDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.util.LocaleUtil;

public class EvaluateNUMBERVALUE {

 public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelWithNUMBERVALUE.xlsx"));    
  
  String[] functionNames = { "_xlfn.NUMBERVALUE" } ;
  FreeRefFunction[] functionImpls = { new NumberValue() } ;
  UDFFinder udfs = new DefaultUDFFinder( functionNames, functionImpls ) ;
  UDFFinder udfToolpack = new AggregatingUDFFinder( udfs ) ;    
  workbook.addToolPack(udfToolpack);
  
  LocaleUtil.setUserLocale(Locale.US);
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
  
  for (Sheet sheet: workbook) {
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
     System.out.println(cellValue);
    }
   }   
  }
 }
}
```

Class `NumberValue` used in above code:

```
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ValueEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.EvaluationException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction;
import org.apache.poi.util.LocaleUtil;


public final class NumberValue implements FreeRefFunction  {
 @Override
 public ValueEval evaluate( ValueEval[] args, OperationEvaluationContext ec ) {
     
  Locale locale = LocaleUtil.getUserLocale();
  DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
  
  String text = null;
  //If the Decimal_separator and Group_separator arguments are not specified, separators from the current locale are used.
  String decSep = String.valueOf(decimalFormatSymbols.getDecimalSeparator());
  String groupSep = String.valueOf(decimalFormatSymbols.getGroupingSeparator());

  Double result = Double.NaN;
  ValueEval v1 = null;
  ValueEval v2 = null;
  ValueEval v3 = null;
  
  try {
   if (args.length == 1) {  
    v1 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue( args[0], ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex());
    text = OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(v1);
   } else if (args.length == 2) { 
    v1 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue( args[0], ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex());
    v2 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue( args[1], ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex());
    text = OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(v1);
    decSep = OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(v2).substring(0, 1); //If multiple characters are used in the Decimal_separator or Group_separator arguments, only the first character is used.
   } else if (args.length == 3) { 
    v1 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue( args[0], ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex());
    v2 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue( args[1], ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex());
    v3 = OperandResolver.getSingleValue( args[2], ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex());
    text = OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(v1);
    decSep = OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(v2).substring(0, 1); //If multiple characters are used in the Decimal_separator or Group_separator arguments, only the first character is used.
    groupSep = OperandResolver.coerceValueToString(v3).substring(0, 1); //If multiple characters are used in the Decimal_separator or Group_separator arguments, only the first character is used.
   }
  } catch (EvaluationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace() ;
   return e.getErrorEval();
  }  
  
  if("".equals(text)) text = "0"; //If an empty string ("") is specified as the Text argument, the result is 0.
  text = text.replace(" ", ""); //Empty spaces in the Text argument are ignored, even in the middle of the argument. For example, " 3 000 " is returned as 3000.
  String[] parts = text.split("["+decSep+"]");
  String sigPart = "";
  String decPart = "";
  if (parts.length > 2) return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID; //If a decimal separator is used more than once in the Text argument, NUMBERVALUE returns the #VALUE! error value.
  if (parts.length > 1) {
   sigPart = parts[0];
   decPart = parts[1];
   if (decPart.contains(groupSep)) return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID; //If the group separator occurs after the decimal separator in the Text argument, NUMBERVALUE returns the #VALUE! error value.
   sigPart = sigPart.replace(groupSep, ""); //If the group separator occurs before the decimal separator in the Text argument , the group separator is ignored.
   text = sigPart + "." + decPart;
  } else if (parts.length > 0) {
   sigPart = parts[0];
   sigPart = sigPart.replace(groupSep, ""); //If the group separator occurs before the decimal separator in the Text argument , the group separator is ignored.
   text = sigPart;
  } 
  
  //If the Text argument ends in one or more percent signs (%), they are used in the calculation of the result. 
  //Multiple percent signs are additive if they are used in the Text argument just as they are if they are used in a formula. 
  //For example, =NUMBERVALUE("9%%") returns the same result (0.0009) as the formula =9%%.
  int countPercent = 0;
  while (text.endsWith("%")) {
   countPercent++;
   text = text.substring(0, text.length()-1);   
  }
    
  try {  
   result = Double.valueOf(text);
   result = result / Math.pow(100, countPercent); //If the Text argument ends in one or more percent signs (%), they are used in the calculation of the result. 
   checkValue(result);
  } catch (EvaluationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace() ;
    return e.getErrorEval();
  } catch (Exception anyex) {
    return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID; //If any of the arguments are not valid, NUMBERVALUE returns the #VALUE! error value.
  }
  
  return new NumberEval(result);
 
 }
 
 static final void checkValue(double result) throws EvaluationException {
  if (Double.isNaN(result) || Double.isInfinite(result)) {
   throw new EvaluationException(ErrorEval.NUM_ERROR);
  }
 }
}
```

What about the prefix `_xlfn.`?

Excel uses this to mark functions which were introduced after Excel 2007. The prefix is stored as part of the function name. If the Excel version knows that function because it is later than Excel 2007, then the GUI will not show that prefix and evaluates the function. If the Excel version doesn't know that function, then the GUI will show the prefix to inform the user about that incompatibility. See [Issue: An _xlfn. prefix is displayed in front of a formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/issue-an-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025)

Since the prefix is stored, the user defined function must be registered having the function name including the prefix: `String[] functionNames = { "_xlfn.NUMBERVALUE" };`.

---

This code is public available. It is free to be reused in any kind of project. Of course it is without any warranty from my side.

Comment: if you give your permission to reuse your code, I might have time to add to POI code base

Comment: the reason Apache committers can't copy paste code from stackoverflow: https://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html#stackoverflow

Comment: @PJ Fanning: See supplements in my answer. Is that enough?

Comment: Thanks Axel - I raised https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65846

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer that explained every single bit that I want to know. please also help take a look at [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855089/how-many-functions-are-supported-by-apache-poi-and-where-these-missing-function)