# How many Functions are supported by Apache POI? and where these missing functions

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on a project that is using a spreadsheet with a very complex mathematical model.
from Apache official document, it listed 302 [supported functions as of July 2021](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#appendixA), however, if we call `WorkbookEvaluator.getSupportedFunctionNames()`, there are only 202. why there is 100 difference? especially these statistic functions such as NORMDIST, NORMINV, etc?
if there is a lib that includes the missed 100 functions where can I find them?

Comment: Which version of POI are you using to run the `WorkbookEvaluator.getSupportedFunctionNames()` function?

Comment: 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.0'

Comment: PJ Fanning, he is not complaining about the number of supported function VS the ones that he would like, but the number of supported functions specified in the POI code itself and the POI documentation itself. I think it is a fair and interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI's documentation is a little bit unclear in this case. So I will try to shed more light.

At first: All the following is state of 2022-01-26, `Apache poi 5.2.0`.

**Excel functions which are implemented or only known by name**

[Developing Formula Evaluation -> What functions are supported?](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#What+functions+are+supported?) tells:

> As of July 2021, POI supports 302 built-in functions, see Appendix A
> for the full list.

But that's not really true. It better should read: "POI knows 393 built-in functions by name.", because not all those functions are implemented yet.

```
  // list of functions that POI can evaluate
  java.util.Collection<String> supportedFuncs = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getSupportedFunctionNames();
  System.out.println("Following functions are implemented by Apache POI:");
  System.out.println("Count: " + supportedFuncs.size());
  System.out.println(supportedFuncs);
```

lists 202 functions which are implemented.

```
  // list of functions that are known but not supported by POI
  System.out.println("Following functions are known by name by Apache POI but not implemented yet:");
  java.util.Collection<String> unsupportedFuncs = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getNotSupportedFunctionNames();
  System.out.println("Count: " + unsupportedFuncs.size());
  System.out.println(unsupportedFuncs);
```

lists 191 functions that are known by name but not implemented yet.

These 191 functions lacks the Java implementation code. They are known by name but `WorkbookEvaluator` will not be able to evaluate them. So `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException` will be thrown.

**How to implement known but not implemented functions?**

The Java code can be implemented as described in [Developing Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html). But there is a further hurdle.

[Developing Formula Evaluation -> Two base interfaces to start your implementation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#Two+base+interfaces+to+start+your+implementation):

> All Excel formula function classes implement either the
> `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Function` or the
> `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction`
> interface. `Function` is a common interface for the functions defined
> in the Binary Excel File Format (BIFF8): these are "classic" Excel
> functions like SUM, COUNT, LOOKUP, etc. `FreeRefFunction` is a common
> interface for the functions from the Excel Analysis ToolPak, for User
> Defined Functions that you create, and for Excel built-in functions
> that have been defined since BIFF8 was defined.

So for the implementation one needs to know which of these 191 functions needs implementing `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Function` and which of them needs implementing `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction` .

```
  // list of ATP functions that are known but not supported by POI
  System.out.println("Following functions are ATP functions known by name by Apache POI but not implemented yet:");
  java.util.Collection<String> unsupportedFuncsATP = org.apache.poi.ss.formula.atp.AnalysisToolPak.getNotSupportedFunctionNames();
  System.out.println("Count: " + unsupportedFuncsATP.size());
  System.out.println(unsupportedFuncsATP);
```

lists 83 functions that are **A**nalysis**T**ool**P**ak functions known by name but not implemented yet. For those the implementation needs implementing `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction`.

```
  // list of BIFF8 functions that are known but not supported by POI
  System.out.println("Following functions are BIFF8 functions known by name by Apache POI but not implemented yet:");
  java.util.List<String> unsupportedFuncsBIFF8 = unsupportedFuncs.stream().filter(n -> !unsupportedFuncsATP.contains(n)).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
  System.out.println("Count: " + unsupportedFuncsBIFF8.size());
  System.out.println(unsupportedFuncsBIFF8);
```

lists 108 functions that are "classic" Excel functions known by name but not implemented yet. For those the implementation needs implementing `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Function`.

**What about Excel functions outside those lists?**

Excel functions which neither are implemented nor known by name must be implemented as user defined functions. This is described in [User Defined Functions](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html). This is basically to implement user defined functions, which are in VBA or in Add-Ins. But it  also can be used to implement new Excel functions which not even known by name in Apache POI. I have shown an example for implementing [NUMBERVALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844731/how-to-use-excel-text-function-numbervalue-from-apache-poi-formula/70849809#70849809) function.

**Why the need to implement Java function code at all?**

Apache POI's approach is handling Microsoft Office files without the need of an installed Microsoft Office application. So Apache POI cannot access the implemented Excel functions because there is no Excel application. So all needed functions need to be implemented by own code.

Main problem here is that the source code of the single Excel functions is closed source and so not public available. Only possibility is to implement the code according to the published function descriptions. That often leads to discrepancies between the results of  Java-implemented function code and Excel function code. The problem increases in border-line use cases of the functions. For example if parameters are omitted or if parameters are set using not expected types. So don't be surprised if the result of the formula evaluation of Apache POI differs from the one of Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, your answer clarified with good examples about how to implement not-supported in build functions and also Macros

Comment: But `NUMBERVALUE` function is already implemented, but cannot be used, why? [NUMBERVALUE impl](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/REL_5_2_2/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/NumberValueFunction.java)

Comment: @Nickon: My answer is from January 2022. NUMBERVALUE function is implemented since Version 5.2.1 (2022-03-03). So what exactly means "cannot be used"? What are you doing to use it?

Answer (score 0):

In response to PJ Fanning, and in case anyone needs to use NORMDIST.

public final class NormDist implements Function {

```
@Override
public ValueEval evaluate(ValueEval[] args, int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex) {
    try {
        final ValueEval x = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(args[0], srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
        final ValueEval mean = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(args[1], srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
        final ValueEval sd = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(args[2], srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
        final ValueEval cumulative = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(args[3], srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
       
        return new NumberEval(this.compute(OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(x),
                OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(mean),
                OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(sd),
                OperandResolver.coerceValueToBoolean(cumulative, true)));
    } catch (EvaluationException e) {
        return e.getErrorEval();
    }
}

public double compute(double x, double mean, double sd, boolean cumulative) {
    try {
        NormalDistribution normDist = new NormalDistribution(mean, sd);
        if(cumulative)
            return normDist.cumulativeProbability(x);
        
        return normDist.density(x);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

}